# How to calculate average response time from the csv file that JMeter produces?

Tags: csv, time, jmeter, response, average

I am running the Ant task to run my JMeter script or jmx file. The script runs smooth and produces a csv file with the following (standard) information: timeStamp, elapsed, label, responseCode, threadName, success, bytes, grpThreads, allThreads, Latency, sampleCount, ErrorCount and Hostname.

My question is: how can I calculate the average response time from this CSV file? What is the formula? I know how to load the CSV file into MS-Excel but simply don't know what is the relationship among the elapsed time and latency with the average response time.

Can anyone please provide the formula with some explanations, if possible. Thank you!

--Ishti

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Average response time is a simple arithmetic mean of all `elapsed` (second) column values

You can ignore the `Latency` value, as per [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) guide

> LATENCY is the delay involved for your request to reach the server.
>   The response time that is required to receive a response from the server is the sum of the **response time + latency**.

Given a simple test plan which executes 2 requests to http://example.com domain, result .jtl file looks as follows:

> 1411131392025,**1002**,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,1591,1002
>   1411131393151,**187**,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,1591,179

If you open this file with [View Results in Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listener the output will be as below:

[image: View Results in Table]

Opening the same file in the Aggregate Report listener gives the following output:

[image: Aggregate Report]

So as you can see `Average` time is `594` ms. It's calculated as `(1002 + 187) / 2`

In Excel or equivalent you can use [Average](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/average-HP005208994.aspx) function:

[image: Excel Average]

For other fields formulae refer to JMeter's [Calculator class source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java)

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, too. I wish there was a way to accept both the responses as answers (I don't have enough reputation to upvote your response). Thank you also for explaining the relationship between the elapsed time and average response time.

Answer (score 3):

To apply the formula for Average Response Time, you should have values of individual response time first. which is not available as per your statement above.

```
<jmeter jmeterhome="C:\apache-jmeter-2.11"
testplan="${basedir}\tests\Loadtest.jmx"
resultlog="${basedir}\tests\LoadtestResults.jtl">
<property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="csv" />
</jmeter>
```

As stated in build.xml, you have to take the resultlog "LoadtestResults.jtl"

and process it as stated below to get the Response time, error%, etc.

> java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv "C:\Aggregate_Report.csv" --input-jtl "C:\tests\LoadtestResults.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport

hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you very much! This plugin saves me some extra work. I would not need to import the csv file to Excel and then do the calculations manually.